# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}^2 - a_{n+1}^2)$ also converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here's the answer of chatGPT:

> To prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 - a_{n+1}^2)$ converges, given that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, we can use the telescoping series technique.
>
> Let's start by expanding the terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 - a_{n+1}^2)$:
> $$\require{cancel}
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 - a_{n+1}^2) &= (a_1^2 - a_2^2) + (a_2^2 - a_3^2) + (a_3^2 - a_4^2) + \ldots \
> \\
> &= a_1^2 + (-a_2^2 + a_2^2) + (-a_3^2 + a_3^2) + (-a_4^2 + a_4^2) + \ldots \
> \\
> &= a_1^2 + \cancel{(-a_2^2 + a_2^2)} + \cancel{(-a_3^2 + a_3^2)} + \cancel{(-a_4^2 + a_4^2)} + \ldots \
> \\
> &= a_1^2
> \end{align*}
> $$

> As you can see, all the terms cancel out except for the first term $a_1^2$. Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 - a_{n+1}^2)$ reduces to the single term $a_1^2$. Hence, it converges.
>
> In conclusion, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 - a_{n+1}^2)$ also converges, and its sum is equal to $a_1^2$.

I'm confused about where the condition was used.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I've corrected the title.

Comment: ChatGPT solution is not formally correct. Use partial sums and the fact that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges then $a_n\to 0$

Comment: Sum up to $N$ ($N$th partial sum), and see what you get. What happens if you take $N\to +\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChatGPT... come on, man. We are mathematicians, think for yourself. First of all since $$\sum a_n<+\infty,$$ we have that $a_n\to 0.$ Now $$\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n^2-a_{n+1}^2)=(a_1^2-a_2^2)+(a_2^2-a_3^2)+\cdots+(a_N^2-a_{N+1}^2)=a_1^2-a_{N+1}^2\to a_1^2,$$ as $N\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, the condition was used to prove that the term $a_n^2$ converges to $0$.  If that wasn't the case, the infinite sum wouldn't converge to $a_1^2$, since up to the $n-th$ term it would give $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n (a_k^2 -a_{k+1}^2)=a_1^2-a_{n+1}^2$ and so if you make $n$ approach to infinity it actually converges to $a_1^2$, since $a_n^2$ approaches $0$.

I would like to point out though, that you should avoid using chatGPT to solve for you problems that you don't know how to solve yourself. It can actually produce a viable output, but as far as I know it can also produce a complete gibberish (mathematically speaking).